# How to create text fields dynamically

Tags: frp, elm

Say I have a record like this:

```
type Library = { books : [Book] }
type Book = { title : String, year : Int }
```

And I want to dynamically create a UI to fill the Library record.
I would want a button "Add" which would create two text fields per book.

And editing inside any text field would immediately be synced in the record structure.

How could I achieve this with elm 0.12?

Comment: I don't know much about elm, but in regular Haskell I would use either the `State` monad or `IORef`s to manage state.  `IORef`s force you to live in the `IO` monad, though.  A side note, your record syntax is invalid, you should have something more like `data Library = Library { books :: [Book] }` and `data Book = Book { title :: String, year :: Int }`.  They have to be declared with `data`, given a constructor, and types are indicated with a double colon.

Comment: bheklilr: his record syntax is fine. He is writing in Elm, not Haskell.

Comment: @WolfeFan Again, don't really know much about Elm, I will keep that in mind when I see Elm specific posts in the future.

Comment: "please, do my homework for me". What have you tried? What didn't work? Where do you think you went wrong? We are not here to do the thinking for you.

Comment: Is there any need to tag this question with Haskell? I don't see a need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn about [interactive UI elements](http://elm-lang.org/learn/Interactive-UI-Elements.elm) and understand the [TODO list example](https://github.com/evancz/TodoFRP), which is pretty much isomorphic with what you want to acquire.

Comment: The first link is broken. [This PR](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-lang.org/pull/227) should fix it.